# Micronaut Redis Lettuce Cache Conditionally Enable

Tags: java, redis, configuration, micronaut, lettuce

For Micronaut Redis, is there a way to toggle whether or not caching is enabled using configuration properties? I see some other available caches have the ability to be enabled/disabled via configuration properties such as [Ehcache](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-cache/snapshot/guide/index.html#ehcache).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe bit late but:

Add in your pom.xml the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-cache-noop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or gradle:

```
implementation("io.micronaut.cache:micronaut-cache-noop:2.3.0")
```

And in your `application.yml` (at this point you can user env variables)

```
noop-cache.enabled: true
```

Source: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-cache/latest/guide/#noop